# How to customize mention notifications in liferay 7.3.5

Tags: java-8, liferay, liferay-7

I'm working with Liferay 7.3.5, and I wish to customize the notification a user gets when he/she is mentioned in a message boards thread, using the @ functionality. I've looked at the official documentation and found that I can edit the email template, but that is not what I want. I wish to customize the notification you get on the website.

For context I'd like to edit the message itself and also the link to the message board. I hope this is enough information, anyone an idea as to how I could tackle this?